# pushsharp for the HTML5 mobile application

Tags: html, pushsharp

I am following the following article:

URL: https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-Apple-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp

Step 1 to Step 20 are convered sucessfully.

Now Step 21 and Step 22 of concern article has some code that is not working in HTML5 web application.

@Experts: If somebody have implement this on HTML5 web application please help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement it using Phonegap/Cordova.

I used the code from [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-Apple-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp)  in my windows service that is used to send out notifications.

Javascript API is used to register for/handle incoming notifications on the client side (html).

Comment: hi - thanks for your response. i looking for same solution, plz help me with code.

Comment: hi DZL, in the concern article step 21 and 22 is written in which application. can i use it in console app if yes, then where notification will populate.

Comment: There is a folder Samples in the solution which is a Console application written in C#. You just create your own certificate, get your device id, change it in the code and run it (for ios). If you did set up everything you should be able to see the notification on your device.

Comment: Hi DZL what is the  javascript API / code used in phonegap to consume notifications coming from pushharp

Comment: @ineffablep you will need to write native code for android/ios to intercept the notifications - that can not be done with javascript/phonegap

Comment: Javascript API is used to register for/handle incoming notifications on the client side  -> how do you register , do you have example of this project

Comment: Registering for push 
`var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
            pushNotification.registerDevice({ alert: true, badge: true, sound: true }, function (status) {
                if (status && status.deviceToken) {
                    //send status.deviceToken to the server
                }
            });`